¿Cómo cargar una imagen a una LISTA de Sharepoint usando Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0?
Estoy intentando cargar una imagen en una lista específica de SharePoint usando la API REST de Microsoft Graph v1.0, pero me cuesta entender cómo hacerlo correctamente. He estado buscando documentación y ejemplos, pero aún no he encontrado una solución clara.
¿Cómo subir una imagen a una "LISTA" de SharePoint usando Graph?
En mi caso ya logré subir un archivo a una carpeta como documento convirtiendo el
imagen a una matriz de bytes.
Fue realmente fácil cargar imágenes en una biblioteca de documentos en SharePoint.
PERO La idea es subir la imagen a una LISTA y se requiere que sea de tipo imagen, no sé qué esperas que envíe la API ahí.
Un elemento de lista de SharePoint es una fila de datos en una lista de SharePoint, que es una colección de información organizada en filas y columnas.
He probado varios métodos en la documentación sin obtener ningún resultado.
GraphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldsToUpdate);
GraphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].Fields.Request().CreateAsync(fieldsToUpdate);
GraphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items.Request().AddAsync(ListItem);
En la documentación no hay ejemplos de montaje de una imagen:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
Crean un JSON pero envían solo texto sin formato.
También he enviado la dirección de la imagen pero me sale error.
ESTE ES MI CÓDIGO:
Mi método que carga en una carpeta funciona bien.
    public async static Task uploadFile(string image,string sku)
{
    try
    {                      
        await UploadFileToSharePoint(_graphServiceClient, image, sku);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Detalles del error : {ex}");
    }
}

public async static Task UploadFileToSharePoint(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string image, string sku)
{
    string graphClient_Sites = _settings.graphClient_Sites;
    string FolderSharePoint = _settings.FolderSharePoint;
    byte[] fileBytes;
    string fileName;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        await fileStream.ReadAsync(fileBytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(image);
        fileName = fileInfo.Name;
    }
    try
    {
        // Subir la imagen como un adjunto
        var driveItem = await graphClient.Sites[graphClient_Sites].Drive.Root
            .ItemWithPath($"{FolderSharePoint}/{sku}_{fileName}")
            .Content
            .Request()
            .PutAsync<DriveItem>(new MemoryStream(fileBytes));
        Console.WriteLine($"Upload complete: {driveItem.Name}");
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Detalles del error : {ex.Error}");
    }
}

con este no he podido subir la imagen:
    public async static Task UpdateListItemFields(GraphServiceClient graphClient , string siteId , string listId , string itemId , string image)
{
    byte[] fileBytes;
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        await fileStream.ReadAsync(fileBytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(image);
    }
    string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);


    var fieldsToUpdate = new FieldValueSet
    {
      AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>             
      {
        {
          "Title", "322" 
        }
      }
    };

    var ListItem = new ListItem
    {
       Fields= new FieldValueSet
             {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"Title", "322"},
                        //{"ImageColumnName", new {Data = base64Image}}
                    }
             }
    };

    //await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldsToUpdate);
    //await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].Fields.Request().CreateAsync(fieldsToUpdate);
    await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items.Request().AddAsync(ListItem);
}

